# SQL Server - @@connections value increasing automatically?

Tags: sql-server, global-variables, connection

I just started learning SQL Server v2014, about the global variables.

```
select @@CONNECTIONS conns, @@MAX_CONNECTIONS mx_conns;
```

With every execution of this query, the value of @@CONNECTIONS is changing. As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ms188915(v=sql.110).aspx), it says attempted successful/unsuccessful attempts. But, since it is a local installation, nobody else is trying to access it. How is the value changing?

Response much appreciated.

Regards,
Ranit

Comment: Possible items that could increase the count of connections include internal SQL Server processes, maintenance processes, scheduled jobs, and (depending on how it is done) running this query.  If you run this with a one second wait between runs, how much does the value increase?

Comment: Roughly it is getting incremented every 10s, but not by a constant factor everytime... But, I got your point and understood that there could be SQL Server internal processes which try to connect itself. Right?

Comment: Correct. SQL Server rarely just sits there waiting for something to do. You might have SQL Agent looking for jobs, or some maintenance process (internal or external) kicking off looking to see if it needs to clean / organize / purge something, or a ton of other things.  With an increment of about 10 seconds, I wouldn't worry much about it. HOWEVER....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to see what is triggering the increase here, set up a SQL Server Profiler trace on your local SQL instance to log everything. Let it run for a few minutes, then shut it off and look at the results.